# What is the difference between psm and cph in RMS package in R

Tags: r, rms

I have a survival data, but I'm not sure what's the different between psm and cph.
How can I determine the model?

Different model will establish the different  nomogram, but I'm not really sure which model I should use?

```
library(rms)
f2 <- psm(Surv(follow_time_5y, DEATH_5y) ~ age+ID_SEX+MH_CCI_total_score, 
          data =sci_20190505, dist='lognormal')

f2 <- cph(Surv(follow_time_5y, DEATH_5y) ~ age+ID_SEX+MH_CCI_total_score, 
               data =sci_20190505,x=TRUE,y=TRUE,surv=TRUE, time.inc=1825)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending of what you want.

PSM:

> psmis a modification of Therneau survreg function for fitting the accelerated failure time family of parametric survival models.psmuses therms class for automatic anova, fastbw, calibrate, validate, and other functions.Hazard.psm,Survival.psm,Quantile.psm, and Mean.psmcre-ate S functions that evaluate the hazard, survival, quantile, and mean (expected value) functions analytically, as functions of time or probabilities and the linear predictor values.

---

CPH:

> Modification of Therneau coxph function to fit the Cox model and its
>   extension, the Andersen-Gill model.  The latter allows for interval
>   time-dependent covariables, time-dependent strata, and repeated 
>   events. The Survival method  for  an  object  created  by cph returns 
>   an  S  function  for computing estimates of the survival function.
>   The Quantile method for cph returns an S function for computing quantiles
>   of survival time (median, by default).

---

So to answer your question: 
"Whats the difference?"

The difference is in the model used.

psm (parametric survival model) uses a survival model based on functions and their parameters. 
A good paper for parametric survival is [this](https://data.princeton.edu/pop509/ParametricSurvival.pdf)

cph (Cox Proportional Hazards Model and Extensions) is using the cox model (and the Anderson-Gill model) which is based on the hazard functions.
You can check the wikipedia article [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proportional_hazards_model#cite_note-5)

Comment: For questions like. "What should i use now" or further details to the models, try opening a question on https://stats.stackexchange.com/ , since this would be off topic here. Also in normally those question can't be answered generally. It depends of what you want and what your data is, mostly you can compare multiple approaches. So try to understand the models and use them like you need to